# Getting error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" when using MySQL and Authorization

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net-4.8

I have an ASP.NET project running on .NET Framework 4.8 and using MySQL for the database. Everything was working fine, till I decided to user Authorization. I have the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class ApproveActionsController : DaysOffBaseController
{
}
```

The moment I try to access the URL: https://myApp/DayOffModule/ApproveActions/ApproveDaysOffList

I'm getting the following error message and the app is throwing SqlException

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have read a lot and it looks like it's thinking that it thinks I'm using SQL Server or trying to connect to it. I have tried looking everywhere in the app for `System.Data.SqlClient` and changed it to `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` but it's still throwing the same Exception.

When I remove the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` from the controller above - I'm not having this issue.

Here is the entire stack:

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

    If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
    If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
    Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
    The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.



Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1524
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +706
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +57
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1186
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +82

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +175
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +121
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +57
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +475
```

Comment: The actual exception call stack can tell you where you forgot to adjust. If you don't share the entire code base, no answer is expected here.

Comment: @LexLi, I have added the entire stack trace. Maybe you will be kind enough to share to show where I forgot to adjust as it looks like I'm missing something. What do you mean by entire code base - the controller, the DbContext file? Hope you will understand that I cannot share the entire solution....

Comment: It is rather hard to dive further because 1) .NET Framework is not fully open sourced 2) The exception call stack is incomplete. Rough analysis on https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource seems to indicate that you failed to override the default ASP.NET providers, so SQL Server ones are still active. Did you follow this guide to configure or another article? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-asp-provider.html

Comment: @LexLi, this is a project a took over from someone and I'm not sure what was actually done before or what was followed or not. I'm getting the exception above when I try to use the Role Authorization, everything else is working just fine and there are no issues when I'm performing CRUD operations on the MySQL database... I really have no clue why this is happening when I add the Role authorization and not during rest of the time,

Comment: You will have to review how you took over the project. For example, the MySQL.com article does indicate quite a few changes you need to make to the development machine. If those changes are not in place, then any issue can happen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep digging into that